# Can we run 2 SFTP Client in a same machine to connect to same SFTP server on different machine using different sockets?

Tags: python, sftp

**Hello Gentlemen**

---

I am trying working in SFTP Server using python (paramiko). My projects needs my client to periodically upload a file (say 10 seconds) but simultaneously have to download a crucial file (say every 1 second). I tried threading but It throws me Continuous errors so Instead I thought of running two separate SFTP clients in the same machine. So that when one uploads the file to the server for every 10 seconds the other downloads simultaneously every 1 seconds. but is it possible to so. because when I tried executing the second client program when first client program is running smoothly I am getting SSH protocol banner error, Can someone provide me a workaround over this issue

Thanks Gentlemen

Regards
Mr.B

Comment: This should be no problem at all. You just have to make sure the server accepts multiple simultaneous connections from the same device and/or with the same user.

Comment: Thanks Mr.Lenniey . But do you have any idea how to allow multiple clients simultaneously in paramiko python library

Comment: IMHO, Your first approach (one thread per client) is the good one. Manage to fix your errors and it'll be ok :)

Comment: Hello, Mr.binarym In my first approach I am not using one thread per client, Im using one process per thread to be precise I used one thread to download in a stipulated time interval and another separate thread or even main thread to upload file in some other time interval but it shows SSH banner error

Answer (score 0):

**Hi Gentlemen**

---

Thanks for the comments, Finally I figured out a solution.I was able to create two SFTP clients on the same machine. The only thing I struggled was on the Server Side where I was using a Single threaded server so it can handle only one client at a time so I altered the SFTP Server to support multiple thread using the code in the link as reference now I am able to connect two clients without a problem

https://gist.github.com/Girgitt/2df036f9e26dba1baaddf4c5845a20a2

Thanks to Mr.Lenniey and Mr.binarym

Regards,

Mr.B